# Eclipse key mappings confused

Tags: eclipse, mapping, key

I'm trying to use eclipse on Win 7, but for some reason it is screwing up my keys.

For example, when I press '{' it ends up displaying a '^'. Im pretty sure that this is what would happen if I had a french keyboard layout, but I'm pretty sure that my language settings in Windows 7 are set to use Canadian English. Firefox or notepad don't have a problem, so I guess that means it's eclipse.

Any idea how to fix it? Right now I'm just copying and pasting symbols lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows XP has a feature that swaps keyboard layout if you hit a key combination (default is left alt + shift). Since it appears to remap on a per-application basis, you might think it is a problem with Eclipse since it won't appear to affect another application. This feature is especially a problem with Eclipse since some useful keybindings may use alt + shift + something and if you don't press the something part, your keyboard layout will switch.

To disable, open the Text Services and Input Languages dialog (easiest way is to right click on the task bar, choose Toolbars > Language bar then right click on the Language bar icon and select Settings...)

In the dialog, click on the Key Settings button. In the Advanced Key Settings, select Switch between input languages and click Change Key Sequence... Deselect the Switch input languages and Switch keyboard layouts checkboxes then hit OK.

While you're in the Advanced Key Settings dialog, if you have any of the language specific hotkeys set, you may want to disable those as well. Just select Switch to (language) and then repeat deselecting the Enable key sequence checkbox and hit OK.

By the way, if you don't want to disable this and your keyboard gets remapped to a foreign language layout, just toggle it back by pressing Alt+Shift (or whatever the combo is).

Comment: +1 Thank you, this answer prevented me from going nuts about that "feature" xD. However, didn't the OP state he's got Win 7, not XP?

Comment: In Windows 7, open "Region and Language" from the Control panel, go to the "Keyboards and Languages" tab, click on "Change keyboards...", click on the "Advanced Key Settings", then go into each setting you want to disable and click the "Not assigned" radio button.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a *french* keyboard layout (which I have right now):

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b9/KB_France.svg/800px-KB_France.svg.png]

, there is no way a <kbd>`{`</kbd> would give you a <kbd>`^`</kbd>.
That would be the same with a canadian english layout:

[image: Keyboard_Layout_Canadian_French]

The only way would be for you type first the  <kbd>`^`</kbd>, since it is a [combining character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character). Then another non-combining character like <kbd>`{`</kbd> would display both the caret and the curly bracket.

---

Eclipse shouldn't mess with your language setting, unless you are using certain plugin like CDT which has a [Language mappings](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/reference/cdt_u_prop_general_lng.htm) property:

[image: Prop lang]

Comment: Yup, it's exactly what the french mappings are.

Shift + '[' should give me a '{' on my keyboard, but it's giving me the french equivalent '^'.

I don't have any CDT plugins installed, either :(

Answer (score 0):

Just do a Alt+Shift it will switch among the languages of your windows.
For example in my system I have defined two languages German and English So if I do Alt+shift 
It switches to German from English and vise versa.